# Why scanner.hasNext() does not stop the loop, when i put emtry line?

Tags: java, while-loop, java.util.scanner

Code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<>();
        while(scanner.hasNextInt()){
            array.add(scanner.nextInt());
        }
        System.out.println(array);
    }
}
```

Input:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jo7sU.png)

Why while doesnt brake the loop when i enter empty line?

Comment: Do you ever close the input stream? If not, how does the scanner know there won't be another value in the future? [Your code runs fine](https://ideone.com/4kd5I1) if the input is piped in, rather than coming from a terminal.

Comment: Try using a sentinel value that will terminate the loop.For instance if user enters -1 exit the loop and print the contents of the array